# implementing a custom behavior on recyclerview inside coordinatorlayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have 3 views in my layout file with CoordinatorLayout as the root view : AppbarLayout, RecyclerView and a Footer(not visible all the time). Recyclerview implements the default behavior appbar_scrolling_view_behavior, that ideally, brings recyclerview below the appbarlayout. But the recyclerview and footer overlap. To Prevent that, I had to write a custom behavior so that when footer is visible, Recyclerview should make space for the footer. But now, the default behavior of appbar_scrolling_view_behavior is gone and now appbarlayout and recyclerview overlap.[Here is the Image of the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/io2YX.jpg)

Link to the custom behavior i implemented:
https://github.com/Mandeep221/CustomBehaviorForRecyclerview/blob/master/CustomBehavior.java

My Question: How can i implement 2 things(simultaneously in one behavior):

1. get the recyclerview below the appbarlayout inside the co-ordinatorlayout
2. get the recycelerview to make space for the footer if the footer is visible.

If you can suggest some workaround, that would also be great! Thanks alot!

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/list_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
      app:layout_behavior="prokure.it.prokure.Search.NewSearch.CustomBehavior" />


    <prokure.it.prokure.FooterBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/footerBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        //footer child views    

            </LinearLayout>
    </prokure.it.prokure.FooterBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't keep the android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout as root layout.

Add a RelativeLayout as a root layout. Then add android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout with property layout_alignParentTop and layout_above="@+id/footerBar" and set prokure.it.prokure.FooterBarLayout as align parent bottom as second child of RelativeLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footerBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
            android:id="@+id/list_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
             />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <prokure.it.prokure.FooterBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/footerBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            //footer child views    

        </LinearLayout>
    </prokure.it.prokure.FooterBarLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simpler way is to add following lines to your prokure.it.prokure.FooterBarLayout

```
    app:layout_anchor="@id/list_recycler_view"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
```

and keep prokure.it.prokure.FooterBarLayout inside coordinator layout.

Make sure to add an empty cell at the end of the recycler view so that prokure.it.prokure.FooterBarLayout does not overlap with last cell of RecyclerView.